# Screenshot attached in any Jira issue is added in any started TestSession

Tags: jira

I have executed following steps :-

1. Created two issues, let us say `ISSUE-1` and `ISSUE-2`
2. Created a *Test Session* in `ISSUE-1`, let us say `TEST_1_1`
3. Started `TEST_1_1`
4. Attached a *Screenshot* in `ISSUE-2`

Expect Behavior - *Screenshot* should not be present in `TEST_1_1`

Actual Behavior - *Screenshot* is present in `TEST_1_1`

I am using Jira Cloud.

Comment: (How) are Issue-1 and issue-2 linked?

Comment: They are issue within same project, but does not have any link.

Answer (score 0):

Jira is internally using **Capture for Jira** (Zeypher).
This is a bit weird behavior of **Test Session**, because *Test Session* will capturing all activities within the particular project.
It is how *Capture for Jira* is designed.